# Where to find actual list of events for Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento

All links in google and Magento Extensions Developer Guide v.1.0 go to http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method which is broken now.

Where is the actual list of observer events located?

Comment: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/       https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-magento-events

Answer (score 2):

There's actually another way to go about this.

Find the `Mage.php` file in your app folder, it'll have the following method in there:

```php
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

As you can see this has the profiler output the events that are being dispatched on any given page. Be forewarned, there's a lot of them. Duplicates too.

That said, if you don't want to turn on the profiler (check your `index.php`), you can hack a log call in there and check the file. Just remember that if you do this, remove the log line when your done.

Beyond that, I can't do anything but recommend that link the other answer added.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can do a grep on the ./app/code/ directory to generate your own list.

```
grep -Rsn 'Mage::dispatchEvent' . > events.txt
```

Check the answer here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92169/how-to-get-magento-1-9-ces-events-list-and-which-event-is-called-when